# Saving an in-place jquery edit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using [Editable](http://www.arashkarimzadeh.com/jquery/7-editable-jquery-plugin.html) to create a in-place text editor.

The file in question is a simple html to do list, that's locally on my computer.

My question is, I can use Editable to make changes, but on refresh it returns to default. How can I save the changes? Because this is a local file I don't have access to PHP.

I'm not that well versed with Jquery & Javascript, so if your answers could be a bit more complete than usual I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Editable. But generally you need a server page (PHP / ASP /JSP /ASP.NET ) to save the data to a Datasource (SQL server table/MySQL table). When you refresh your browser, it makes a request to the same page again  and it loads data from the server ( that is what you say default). So you have to save the changes to the datasource. You may include a save button in your form and in the click event of that, you can save the data to the datasource. or you can call a javascript function in the onblur event and save the data using ajax.

Comment: I'm not trying to save the data to SQL. It's loading the data from a local html file. Is there no way to have a button save a local file, and overwrite the old one?

Comment: @user974703: what kind of file it is ? is it an xml file or static html file ? if it is am xml file, you can modify it with one of the server side pages

Comment: static html. It's a single file that's i've just styled with css. My attempt at a basic to do list page. I can now edit inline, but I'm having trouble saving the result.

Comment: I seraisly doubt whether you can save the static file from program.

Answer (score 0):

if you want your data to persists without a database or access to other server side programming, you can use cookies.

For more tutorials on this, you can visit [Cookie Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

note: this approach is generally bad, but for prototyping this should be suffice